# Show the bijection between $(a, b)$ and $[a, b]$

Tags: real-analysis, functions

I was thinking two-steps bijection: first showing the bijection between $(a, b)$ and $(a, b]$ and then finalize by showing the bijection between $(a, b]$ and $[a, b]$, but I cannot find any idea to start. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

Hint:

A possible direction:

- Separate the set to a countable and an uncountable set.
- Have you heard of the hotel with countably infinite number of guests?
- For the uncountable set, map the elements to themselves.

Comment: But interval of real numbers is uncountable, how can I apply the second point?

Comment: which is why the first point is needed., the hotel trick is used for the countable part.

Answer (score 2):

For $A$ an infinite set and $B$ a countable set (finite or countably infinite) there is a bijection between $A \cup B$ and $A.$ So for this case, $A = (0, 1)$ is infinite and $B = \{0, 1\}$ is finite. So to see the bijection, take a countably infinite subset of $A, C.$ Construct a bijection between $C \cup \{0, 1\}$ and $C$ and map everything else identically.